# Creating more than one value into one column in mysql

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I am trying create movie ticket application. But I am facing problem in the concept of designing the database. Each movie have 6 attributes which they are: the movie name, description, cinema location, movie time, movie hall, movie poster, and movie unique ID. I designed the database:

[image]

I realize once I insert one movie into the database, I only can add one time 
and one movie hall in the database. Each movie should have more than one 
time and more than one hall in each time. The issue cause I need to populate the movie time and the movie threator into combobox. The only solution I found is to create extra two columns one `UniqeID` for the movie name and location and time. The another column `UniqeID` for the movie name and location and time and the movie hall. So I can populate the movie time using the time `UniqeID` and the movie the hall `UniqeID`. But the solution overall is not efficiency.

Note: I think the question is fundamental but I'm new into relational databases.

I'm using mysql

Comment: 1. You need to read an introduction to relational database design. 2. If the table holds rows where "movie named MOVIE_NAME with description DESCRIPTION is playing in cinema CINEMA_LOCATION..." then it is not true that "once I insert one movie into the database, I only can add one time and one movie hall in the database". You would have multiple rows, some which state the same thing but others which state different things, re halls & times. But we want to avoid rows saying the same thing. *Normalization* deals with that. 3. Why do you think you think "the solution overall is not efficiency"?

Answer (score 1):

You need 3 tables.

theaters
id, name, address

movies
id, name, (other columns)

showtimes
id, theaters_id, movies_id, showtime